# made a network with multiple switches in mininet and add flows to switches manually (by dpctl)

Tags: networking

Can we made a network with multiple switches without any controller in mininet .
I mean that we manually control the switches by "dpctl"
 I made the topology like this:
         s2
        /   \
h1---s1/     \s3--h2 
       \    /
        \s4/
and I want to send from h1 to h2.

first of all that I turn on the floodlight, and I extract the switch port number from there. after that I want to add flows manually that I encountered to an error.

mininet@mininet-vm:~$ dpctl add-flow tcp:127.0.0.1:40566 in_port=1,actions=output:2
dpctl: failed to send packet to switch: Connection refused

how can i fix it??
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
dpctl add-flow tcp:127.0.0.1:6634in_port=1,actions=output:2
```

Port number will be 6634.
Controller is at Port number 6633 and from 6634 you have port for `dpctl`.